# Isomorphisms for a set of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I have the following question here.

> Define functions $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in F$ by
> $$f_1(x)=1,f_2(x)=\cos(x),f_3(x)=\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
> and let $V=\text{Span}(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. Are the spaces $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $V$ isomorphic to each other? If so, provide an isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow V$. Otherwise, explain why not.

I know the vectors are isomorphic since the dimension of $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are the same (Since $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly independent, they can't be written in terms of each other so the dimension of $V$ is $3$ as well).

How do I find the actual isomorphism though? We didn't really do many examples of this in class. I know we need to find an invertible linear transformation but I am genuinely stuck on how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just take any 3 independent elements in one space, any three independent elements in the other space, and map $i$th to $i$th. For instance, $(1,0,0)$ can be mapped to $f_1$, and so on.

Comment: $\varphi(a,b,c) = af_1+bf_2 + cf_3$.

Comment: @PeterFranek would my matrix not just be the identity matrix then?

Comment: Yes, wrt to the basis e1, e2, e3 and f1, f2, f3.

Comment: Would something like "$\varphi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to V$ such that $\varphi (e_i) = f_i(x)$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$" be okay? I think the "proper" notation is what bothers me. @PeterFranek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that whether $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly independent if yes then dimension of $V=3$.
Note that **If $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector space then $V\cong W.$**
You can find this theorem in each book probably.
Good luck!

Comment: I get that, but how do I actually do the transformation? If I go $\varphi{(e_i)}=f_i$, I get the identity matrix on the left side do I not?

Comment: @FutureMathperson I didn't get you. You defined map correctly no show that it is injective, surjective and linearity. Let me know you if there is any problem regarding proving this.